# INSERT with Linq omitting some "fake" columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a table in the database with the following columns: `ID, Name, Txt`. We are using Linq To Sql to implement our DAL. In there another collegue added two extra columns so in the code the same table results: `ID, Name, Txt, NameTemp, TxtTemp`.

These two "fake" tables are used in different parts of the code in LINQ joins and analyzing with SQL Profiler the parsed SQL query takes the "real" columns and everything works properly.
Now I need to make an INSERT using that table, but I get an exception since also the fake columns are used in the statement.

**Since I cannot add the two fake columns in the DB(since unuseful there), is there a way in which I could make an insert with Linq omitting these two columns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know where you're getting at.  You should be able to add properties to a partial linq class no problem, only thing is that if you try and use a linq query against these "fake" columns, you'll get an exception when linqtosql tries to reference a column that doesn't exist in the database.  I've been through this before - i wanted to be able to select columns that don't exist in the database (but do in the linq2sql dbml class) and have linq2sql translate the columns into what they really are in the database.  Only problem is that there's no real easy way to do this - you can add attributes to the "fake" properties so that linq2sql thinks that NameTmp and TxtTmp are in fact Name and Txt in the sql world, only problem is that when it comes to inserting a record, the translated sql specifies the same column twice (which SQL doesn't like and throws an exception).

You can mark the column with IsDbGenerated = true - that'll let you insert records without getting the double column problem, but you can't update a record without linqtosql complaining that you can't update a computed column.  I guess you can use a sproc to get around this perhaps?

I logged a bug with Microsoft a while back, which they'll never fix.  The info here might help you get what you need -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/linqtosql/thread/5691e0ad-ad67-47ea-ae2c-9432e4e4bd46

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526402/linq2sql-doesnt-like-it-when-you-wrap-column-properties-with-properties-in-an-interface

Comment: Hi frank, thanks for the usefuls info. I think I will develop a sp.

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is not for inserting data, but for querying only - Language INtegrated **Query**. Use ADO.NET for inserting the data.

(Leaving the first part to remind my stupidity)
Check [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx). The classes generated are partial (mentioned [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)), so you can put your 2 properties into the editable part and since they won't have any mapping attribute defined, they won't be mapped nor persisted.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: It's an answer - Luca cannot insert data using LINQ.

Comment: Does that mean I also can't insert data using Structured **Query** Language? Linq to SQL is an ORM and it definitely allows insertion of data.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, Luca check this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx. If those 2 properties are not part of the schema (they're not the db columns), then they won't be saved (there's non column for them).

Comment: They are part of the schema since are used as Keys within the Data Context.